# xls file some formula not open in open office

Tags: 10.04, libreoffice, openoffice.org

In my office morethan 50system working in ubuntu desktop ,But the problem is some of macro function not supported in openoffice . the formula values also changed when it is open in openoffice . is any possible to install libre office or any upgrade version in ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 0):

The minimum system requirements for LibreOffice on Linux are [here](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/system-requirements/).

Whether one wants to invest effort upgrading from OpenOffice.org to LibreOffice on systems running Ubuntu 10.04 given that support (for the desktop version) [ends in April 2013](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) is the question.

That macros written for Microsoft Excel don't always "translate" perfectly is not unknown.